# Github avoid conflicts when pulling compiled CSS and JS files to local

Tags: git, github, sass, gulp, git-pull

We're working in a team where we are sharing a compiled CSS and JS files. We are trying to figure out a way to pull code from our Github and avoid merge conflicts. After we pull, we would recompile our files and everything would be fine. I tried a couple of tutorials to avoid conflicts for specific files and nothing has worked:

- https://blog.andrewray.me/dealing-with-compiled-files-in-git/
- http://subhojit777.in/bypass-git-merge-conflict-compiled-css/

Here's what we have tried. this is our `.gitattributes`:

```
/assets/styles/theme-styles.css merge=ours
/assets/styles/theme-styles.css.map merge=ours

/assets/scripts/theme-scripts.js merge=ours
/assets/scripts/theme-scripts.js.map merge=ours
```

Here's our `.git/config`

```
[merge "ours"]
    name = "Keep ours merge"
    driver = true

[pull "ours"]
    name = "Keep ours merge"
    driver = true
```

No matter what we try, we still get errors when
`git pull origin dev`

Does anyone has thoughts on what we're doing wrong. Any thoughts? Thanks in advance

Comment: Is there a valid argument why to keep compiled files in the repository?

Comment: @aventurin from github, we use deploybot to push the most recent commits to our live site. So ideally, we want the most up-to-date compiled files to be in the repo

Comment: OK, I see. But normally I would expect a build step between push and deploy that would compile.

Comment: That's definitely an option. Deploybot can do the last build before deploying on master. But we want to explore first.